# Why can't I change the sstp vpn's port

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, sstp

I'm trying to change sstp vpn's port by changing the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SstpSvc\Parameters\ConfigStore\ ListenerPort` key of my registry but when I change it the regedit show me an error that says `Cannot edit ListenerPort: Error writhing the values's new contents.`

So how can I resolve the problem?

Comment: the port definitely isn't used by something else?

Comment: @kafka How can I understand that. I stopped the service and tried again but there were no changes!

Comment: what are you changing the port from/to? netstat -an from the command line tells you what ports you're already listening on

Answer (score 1):

change the permissions of configstore write for admins

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation of why it fails, and why the proposed solution works.

Comment: take look at the permissions on HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SstpSvc\Parameters\ConfigStore\ ListenerPort there are no write permissions for Administrator - add write permissions , change the port an may be revoke permissions

Answer (score 1):

You can change SSTP port after VPN server stopped. I tested.

Also, windows client needs special treatment:
1. add hosts rule pointing to localhost by remote server name
2. add port redirection to vpn server use

```
 netsh interface portproxy add
```